# Two way function calling (C++ Dynamic Libraries)

Tags: c++, dynamic-loading

I know that when you load a dynamic C++ library using dlopen() you can then get pointers to functions inside that library, but is there a way to efficiently *(performance matters)* do it the other way?

I know that I could just call a function *(when initializing the library)* inside the library passing an array of pointers to functions, or just send the pointers all separately to a function. *(although an array would probably be better because it allows me to add functions yet not require all old plugins to update)*

I'm not really sure if this is efficient as there might be hundred functions and sending all of those to maybe 10 libraries might not be efficient.

But I am not very experienced with Dynamic Libraries so I am just wondering if you guys know of any better was to do this.

EDIT: Maybe put all those functions in a class and then send a class pointer trough a function call? Would that work?

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that the performance cost of getting the function pointers is a high enough fraction of total execution time to be worth worrying about. It's even probably an insignificant fraction of the I/O time needed to load the dlls. Don't solve problems until you know you have them.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey The pointers would have to be scrolled trough and stored a bunch of times causing for the memory to have some trouble.

Comment: @sehe Actually I really want to do this as I would love learning more about C++ etc.

Comment: You really think storing a thousand pointers will be an issue? Even 640K are enough for that!

Comment: I'm not really sure why you would even want to do that - the library would have to have a list of functions it expects to find in any application that ever uses that library, which would extremely limit the usefulness of that library. Callback functions are probably the better way to go...

Comment: @Twalberg the libraries are plugins for this specific application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "But I am not very experienced with Dynamic Libraries"

That's the cue to say: you don't want to do this.

Perhaps look at [Boost Extension](http://boost-extension.redshoelace.com/docs/boost/extension/index.html) (not official part of boost), which takes the high-level, C++ approach here.

That said, most platforms support this to an extent. E.g. XlC++ on AIX has rtld (which requires an explicit 'exported' symbols map, IIRC), and I had the same working on windows and linux (our 3rd-party workflow engine required it). Sending the array of fptrs seems most pragmatic, and closer to the 'plugin' pattern.

Comment: Maybe put all those functions in a class and then send a class pointer trough a function call? Would that work?

Comment: I don't recommend doing this 'without sidewheels'. But yes, in principle there is no big problem. Caveats lie here: ABI compatibility (build all libs with same compiler ***and*** flags); exception-support across module boundaries; undocumented nature of name-mangling and `RTTI`

Comment: Do you mean that if I would point over a class that was compiled  using a different compiler or with different settings it would not work?:O

Comment: Yes, that is what he means. If you're lucky you'll get an error. Most likely you'll get something worse.

Comment: I hope I scared you sufficiently. Here be dragons. C linkage and 'simple' (old fashioned) dynamic loading are my best advice. :)

Comment: @kleist Then how do you not need to recompile the std libraries every time you compile your app? Do they come precompiled with your compiler?

Comment: Just make sure you build against ***and*** run against the exact same shared (runtime) libraries.

Comment: Yes, they do, in at least release and debug versions. (In fact you do recompile a lot of the std libraries for each app since they are templates, but that's a different story.)